# Is it possible to post an entire Javascript object via a Jquery Ajax post to a .Net webservice?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

in the current situation, when we post data from a webpage via the Jquery Ajax post to a webservice, we build a Json string with two or three parameters and we have a webservice with a method that accepts that same (named) parameters.

But now i have an object in my javascript with 10 properties and i was wondering if i can post that entire object to my webservice.

I've tried posting the object and have an type 'Object' parameter in the webservice, but that didn't work.

Comment: Depending on the structure and the content of the object, this should be no problem. What is the structure?

Comment: it's an object with 10 properties (all strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to create a class and make it serializable by using the [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute. You then use DataMember to mark the members of the class to be serialized. Something like this will do:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.yournamespace/")]
public class MyObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your WCF service:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public bool HandleObject(MyObject myObject)
    {

    }
```

In the client code, do something like this:

```
    $.ajax({ url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: '{"myObject":' + json2string(myObject) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {}
    });
```

Comment: what will i send to the service as data? the object, the JSON.Stringify'd version of my object? Can you help me with the calling code?

Comment: by the way, we're using webservices not wcf, does that influence the answer?

Comment: You need to stringify your object. See my edited answer. The serialization part is the same for the classic web services as well. The attributes needed will be different though.